# Convert CSV line to one item per line

Tags: c++, csv, numbers, output

I have to make a TXT file with data coming from a CSV.

They are currently ordered in the format 1,3,2,4,7,2,3,1,4,3 . When 1 is the number to repeat and the next number the times to reapeat.

The objective is make the output with this format:

1

1

1

2

2

2

2

7

7

3

4

4

4

I can currently display only the numbers one below the other but not the repeating. Any help will be appreciated. It's my first post here, so if there's anything wrong let me know, thanks!

```
void lectura(string archivo){
string linea; //string to save the line of numbers
vector <string> numeros; //vector to save the line 
ifstream entrada(archivo.c_str()); //open csv to read
ofstream signal( "datos_de_senial.txt", ios::out); //open csv to write

int pos =0;

while(getline(entrada, linea)){ //get the line
    istringstream in(linea); //convert to istingstream
    string num;
    if(pos==0){
        while (getline(in, num, ',')){ //get the numbers separated by ","
            numeros.push_back(num); //save to vector"numeros"
        }
        for(unsigned int x = 0; x < numeros.size(); x++) //show one number below the other,here i think the problem is
                       signal << numeros[x] << '\n';

    }
}

signal.close(); 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
void lectura(string archivo);

string csv = "signals.csv";
lectura(csv);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your vector is pointless in the posted code (and that indicates where the real problem is; if it is pointless, something to *do* with that vector data is what is missing). You're just filling it, then dumping it to the output file, with no processing of the *data* inside beyond that. The latter (processing the data you're reading and taking appropriate action therein), seems to be what is missing. A discussion with [a rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) about your existing code may be telling, and in fact, hint what is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I drafted an ultra simple solution for you. With that, you can easily see, how to print the values as you wish.

Because of the simplicity of this solution there is no further explanation needed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>

std::regex re(",");

std::string csv{"1,3,2,4,7,2,3,1,4,3"};

int main() {

    // Read all data from the file
    std::vector<std::string> data(std::sregex_token_iterator(csv.begin(),csv.end(),re,-1), {});

    // iterate through data
    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator iter = data.begin(); iter != data.end(); ++iter) {

        // Read the value
        int value = std::stoi(*iter);
        // Point to next value, the repeat count
        ++iter; 
        int repeatCount = std::stoi(*iter);

        // Now output
        for (int i=0; i < repeatCount; ++i)
            std::cout << value << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course there are also many other possible solutions . . .

Comment: This is the best answer for the moment, thank you so much!. Now i have to solve the problem from passing my CSV file to a string and try to apply this syntax